# What are these trailside monuments near Visegrád, Hungary?

Tags: identify-this, religion, hungary

There were around ten of these monuments by the side of the trail from Visegrád, Hungary, to the town's castle. I didn't see any dates or description, but the stone looked quite worn, so they're not *too* recent.

**What do these monuments depict or symbolize?**

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: These are stations of the cross, any Roman Catholic church has or used to have them, inside or out. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stations_of_the_Cross I do not know anything about these particular ones.

Comment: There's nothing specific to Hungary in this question.

Comment: I didn't know that at the time I asked!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[These are stations of the *via crucis* (the Way of the Cross).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stations_of_the_Cross) They represent fourteen events which occurred prior, during and after Jesus was crucified. The Way of the Cross is usually celebrated on Good Friday as a pilgrimage during which believers visit every station. It is not uncommon to find these stations represented on a trail or path leading to a church or monastery, although they are more frequently found inside churches all around the walls. The stations are (quoting from Wikipedia):

> 1. Jesus is condemned to death
> 2. Jesus carries his cross
> 3. Jesus falls the first time
> 4. Jesus meets his mother
> 5. Simon of Cyrene helps Jesus carry the cross
> 6. Veronica wipes the face of Jesus
> 7. Jesus falls the second time
> 8. Jesus meets the women of Jerusalem
> 9. Jesus falls the third time
> 10. Jesus is stripped of his garments
> 11. Crucifixion: Jesus is nailed to the cross
> 12. Jesus dies on the cross
> 13. Jesus is taken down from the cross (Deposition or Lamentation)
> 14. Jesus is laid in the tomb.

Guessing from the photos, the stations you posted could be:

- 1: Jesus is condemned to death / 5: Simon of Cyrene helps Jesus carry the cross
- 6: Veronica wipes the face of Jesus
- 8: Jesus meets the women of Jerusalem

Comment: I am not sure when the tradition started. I do know that new build churches still get the stations.

Comment: It looks to me like the first photograph is Simon helping to carry the cross.

Comment: @phoog You could be right. The fact that a roman guard is pictured in the relief makes me think  that Jesus is being ordered to carry the cross. The man holding it for him could indeed be Simon.

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned, those are stations of the Way of the Cross (*via crucis* in Latin, *kálvária* in Hungarian). These particular stations were created by sculptor [Szakál Ernő in 1961](http://visegrad.utisugo.hu/latnivalok/kalvaria-visegrad-93370.html). The path they're on leads to the Calvary Chapel, which was [built in 1770](http://csendhegyek.blogspot.com/2014/04/visegrad-kalvaria-h_2.html).